# C#: пинг сокета

Tags: c#, сокет, сокеты, ping

Имею такую ситуацию - через сокет подключаюсь к серверу.
Есть ли возможность пинговать открытый сокет? 
Например, раз в промежуток времени послать пинг - если не вернется, убить сокет.

Существует ли такая возможность?

Comment: Вы описываете задачу в очень низкоуровневых терминах. Опишите свою _настоящую_ задачу, которую вы пытаетесь таким образом решить. Возможно, у неё есть другое решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два взаимодополняющих механизма для решения этой проблемы.

Первый - [TCP KeepAlive](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/06/03/things-that-you-may-want-to-know-about-tcp-keepalives.aspx). Он предотвращает закрытие сокета при неактивности (действительно долгой неактивности, по умолчанию интервал таких "пингов" - раз в два часа). Включается следующей строчкой:

```
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
```

Второй - реальная отправка пакета и ожидание ответа, раз в X секунд. Реализация зависит от протокола - сервер должен ожидать что ему придет пинг, и отправлять соответствующий ответ.

Comment: Во втором случае это должна быть известная серверу последовательность байтов или можно просто 1 байт послать? (глупо, наверное, но я пробовал и ничего не вышло :))

Comment: в втором случае все зависит от протокола. Просто послать один байт нельзя.

В случае xmpp протокола такая последовательность есть - нужно послать символ перевода строки.

Comment: @LeonardBertone сервер должен понять что это за байт и прислать ответ. что у вас за сервер?

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за ответ. Что за сервер не знаю, знаю только одно сообщение, которое он понимает. В любом случае, спасибо.

Comment: @LeonardBertone вот это сообщение и шлите раз в пару минут. Ну или экспериментируйте, вдруг подберете еще что-то.

Comment: @Leonard Bertone А вы пробовали просто ping "ваш сервер" в обычной командной строке??(cmd.exe) Может, сервер не отвечает на пинги.  Я так понял вам нужна "страховка"??? Если да и сервер не поддерживает icmp, то можно просто открыть второе соединение, если успех - значит "тестовый пинг" прошёл и отключить 2й TestSocketConnection.Close()  Такой вариант подойдёт?